# Does Lucene use Extended Boolean Model retrieval?

Tags: lucene, information-retrieval

Some time ago I came across [extended boolean model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Boolean_model), which combine boolean retrieval logic with ability to rank documents the way similar to Vector Space Model does.

As far as I understand this is exactly the way Lucene does it's job in ranking documents. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a combination of the Vector Space Model and the Boolean Model. Checkout the [Scoring](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_2_0/scoring.html) docs page:

> Lucene scoring uses a combination of the Vector Space Model (VSM) of Information Retrieval and the Boolean model to determine how relevant a given Document is to a User's query. In general, the idea behind the VSM is the more times a query term appears in a document relative to the number of times the term appears in all the documents in the collection, the more relevant that document is to the query. It uses the Boolean model to first narrow down the documents that need to be scored based on the use of boolean logic in the Query specification.

If you compare the formulas at [Similarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html) with the classic [VSM formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model) you'll note that they are similar (though not equal).